# Is it usual for facultative phenomenons to be socially connoted?

Tags: sociolinguistics

The sandhi phenomenon known as *liaison* in French bears a strong social connotation, that is to say when its realisation is facultative, it is a marker of a high social class.

Are there facultative phenomenons that bears no social connotation?

Comment: Interesting; could you give an example?

Comment: @Cerberus: It is a well-know fact and there is plenty of literature about it. If you seek references I recommend Daan De Jong. An usual example would be “mais aussi”, informally `/mɛosi/` or `/mɛzosi/` depending on the social class of the speaker and the formality of the interaction.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the example and the recommendation, cool! // My French is rusty, but, just out of curiosity: how about the *d* in *pied-à-terre*? Is that always pronounced, or never, or based on class, or something else?

Comment: @Cerberus: It is facultative, but mind the pronunciation `/t/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe there is a very strong connection in many languages, possibly the strongest of all things connected with upper-class speech ("old money", not merely the rich). It is just that facultative phenomena (see what I did there), which I will define as two things between which your choice hardly changes meaning, contain much space for variation, and class markers thrive on variation. Consider the following:

**Synonyms**:

English:

- U: *loo*, etc.
- [Non-U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-U): *toilet*

Dutch:

- U: *plee, wc, < silence >,* etc.
- Non-U: *toilet*

**Pronunciation of foreign words:**

Dutch:

- U: *restaur*/ɑ̃/  (hope I'm getting the a right, and that it is displayed right)
- Non-U: *restaur*/ɑnt/
- U: *engage*/ɑnt/ (sic)
- Non-U/odd: **engage*/ɑ̃/

It should also be noted that *less* articulate speech usually distinguishes upper-class speech from middle-class speech; in RP, I believe, the word *formidable* more or less becomes *fo- < drawl >* in quick speech.

Answer (score 1):

Facultative phenomena can simply bear geographical information, I would say that this is mostly where the social connotations come from in the first place.